# Is it possible to apply Wireshark filter using mask?

Tags: filter, wireshark

What I am trying to achieve if to define a mask that could select frames with corresponding type_subtype:

```
wlan.fc.type_subtype &= 0xc02f
```

Is there some kind of functionality in Wireshark to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:  `wlan.fc.type_subtype & 0xc02f == 0xc02f`.